# Here Maps API - do failures/errors count a transaction

Tags: heremaps

we need to implement our own transactions counting per user system for Here Maps API. The problem is these may often return some strange errors due to internal errors, or because of the user error (invalid params).
What with canceled requests (map tile requests from browser, on the client's map panning; rather obvious but...). The question is if these also count as transaction on the billing.